# Let ${f}$ be a differentiable function in $x=6$ so that $\lim_{x\to6}{\frac{x^{3}f(x)-1512}{x-6}}=262.144$. Find the values of $f(6)$ and $f(6)'$.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

> Let ${f}$ be a differentiable function in $x=6$ so that $$\lim_{x\to6}{\frac{x^{3}f(x)-1512}{x-6}}=262.144$$ Find the values of $f(6)$ and $f(6)'$.

The right answers are, respectively 7 and 1.21.

This was a problem presented in a quiz I had this week in Calculus I. By my understanding it would suffice to do $x^{3}f(x)-1512 = 0$ since the upper part should be $0$ just as $x-6$ for the function to exist in $x=6$. This would return $f(6)=7$. Doing l'Hôpital's rule and deriving the function makes $f(6)'=-2.28$...

My other problem is that using $7$ in the place of $f(x)$ does NOT give a limit of $262.144$ as it's intended. Any enlightnment would be appreciated!

UPDATE:
You can really find $f(6)$ by just isolating it. To get $f(6)'$ it's necessary to use the definition of derivatives when ${x\to6}$. That is:
$\lim_{x\to6}\frac{f(x)-f(6)}{x-6}$. Multiplying both sides by $\frac{1}{x^{3}}$ back in the original limit and using $x=6$ we get to:
$$\lim_{x\to6}\frac{f(x)-7}{x-6} = \frac{262.144}{6^{3}}$$
It looks exactly like f(6)'... Since $\frac{262.144}{6^{3}}=1.21$, that's the derivative wanted.
A huge thanks to the people that helped me understand it here.

Comment: Well we have $f(6)=7$ and not $f(x) =7$ (for all $x$). Hence we can't replace $f(x) $ with $7$.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect there may be a mistake in the given solution. Notice that

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{x\to6}\frac{x^3f(x)-1512}{x-6} &= \lim_{x\to6}\frac{x^3f(x)-216f(x)+216f(x)-1512}{x-6}\\[1ex]
&=\lim_{x\to6}\frac{(x^3-216)f(x)+216(f(x)-7)}{x-6} \\[1ex]
&= \lim_{x\to6}(x^2+6x+36)f(x) + 216\lim_{x\to6}\frac{f(x)-7}{x-6}
\end{align}$$

But if $f(x)$ is differentiable and $f(6)=7$, then $\lim\limits_{x\to6}f(x)=7$, while the second limit is simply $f'(6)$, and this yields the same result,

$$108\cdot7+216f'(6) = 262.144 \implies f'(6) = -2.28\ldots$$

Comment: Firstly, thanks for the reply! But I guess I don't understand properly the answer. By the given solution you mean 7 and 1.21? Because testing using 7 in the problem and inserting it in a limits calculator it seems the limit should actually be 756(?). I don't really know how to get to an answer here.

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant by "given solution". And as another user mentioned, you cannot simply replace $f(x)$ with $7$. Ultimately my solution agrees with yours, just without the use of L'Hopital's rule, and it's my suspicion that the "given solution" is simply incorrect.